# How do I continue from here? (calculating expected value)

Tags: probability, expected-value

In a course in uni there is $185$ students, every students has birthday and his birthday is **uniformly** distributed on the $365$ days in a year. All the birthdays are independent from eachother. During the semster there is $14$ lectures. Whenever there is a lecture on the same date that  at least one of the students has birthday The teacher give a cake to the class. Let $X$ be the number of cakes brought to the class. Calculate $\mathbb{E}[X]$

Well I dont really understand how to approach this problem because I feel there is too many givens here.
I understand that $0\leq X \leq 14$ and I want to use the formula $$
\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum_{t \in R_{X}} t \cdot \mathbb{P}(X=t)
$$
My problem is to calculate $\mathbb{P}(X=t)$ for  $t$ between $0$ to $14$

Comment: I would change the approach. For each $1 \leq j \leq 14$ let $X_j=1$ if a cake was brought to the $j^{\text{th}}$ lecture and $X_j=0$ otherwise. Set $X=X_1+\dots +X_{14}$ and note $$P(X_j=0)=\Big(\frac{364}{365}\Big)^{185}$$ Can you proceed? Also, the problem states that the professor only brings one cake to the class on a day when at least one student has a birthday.

Comment: Do you have the value for the answer?

Comment: @MatthewPilling I don't understand why $P(X_j=0)=\Big(\frac{364}{365}\Big)^{185}$ represent the event that in the $j^{th}$  lecture no one born on this date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X_j$ be a random variable that is equal to $1$ if at least one student has a birthday on   the $j_{th}\;$"lecture day", (so a cake is brought to class) and $0$ otherwise

$\Bbb P(X_j=1) = 1 - \left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{185}$

Now the expectation of an indicator r.v. is just the probability of the event that it indicates,

so $\Bbb E(X_j) = \Bbb P(X_j)$, and by linearity of expectation,

$\Bbb E(X) = \Bbb E(X_1) + \Bbb E(X_2) + ...... \Bbb E(X_{14})$

Comment: Wow this is brilliant! Can you tell me what made you choose random variable like that? where was the "hint" that made you choose random variable like that and not try to calculate it like my approach?

Comment: @Sagigever this is one of those common expected value "tricks" - its something you will see over and over again. Not sure who "originally" came up with it.